# Ag Grid: How do I know which row group was removed when a user removes one?

Tags: angular6, grouping, ag-grid

When using an Ag Grid with Angular 6, when I listen for the columnRowGroupChanged event that fires when "[A row group column was added or removed](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/)", if the user removes a row group, how do I determine which row group was removed?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compare this manually by using **columnApi.getRowGroupColumns()**:

```
  // gets all column definitions that are grouped
  let groupedColumns = this.gridOptions.columnApi.getRowGroupColumns();
```

before/after the **columnRowGroupChanged** event.